# how to assign variable inside switch statement?

Tags: android, kotlin, switch-statement, variable-assignment

I just started using Kotlin. I want to assign a variable inside a switch statement. Here is the code:

```
when (position)
{
   1 -> fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(homeFragment).commit()
        active = homeFragment
}
```

In the above code , in the `active = homeFragment` line, i am getting the following error: `Assignments are not expressions, and only expressions are allowed in this context`

How to solve this issue? Is it not possible to assign variable inside switch case in kotlin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign in this way

```
when (position)
{
    1 -> {

        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(homeFragment).commit()
        active = homeFragment
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
when (position)
{
   1 -> {
         supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(homeFragment).commit()
         active = homeFragment
        }
}
```

Also

You should use **`supportFragmentManager`** insteadof **`fragmentManager`**

> Because `fragmentManager` is deprecated

Use

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(homeFragment).commit()
```

Instead of

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(homeFragment).commit()
```

Comment: ya, i know. I am using `supportFragmentManager`. fragmentManager is just a variable to which `supportFragmentManager` is assigned to.

Comment: @JayeshBabu okay no problem

Answer (score 2):

If your 'when' sentence is going to have more than one options with the same structures you can make it return the value of the fragment selected, for instance:

```
active = when(option) {
             1 —> homeFragment.also {
                      fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(it).commit()
                  }
         }
```